# How to allow for arbitrary number of wildcards in regexes?

Tags: regex, r

I have a list of character strings:

```
> head(g_patterns_clean_strings)
[[1]]
[1] "1FAFA"

[[2]]
[1] "FA,TRFA"

[[3]]
[1] "FAEX"
```

I am trying to identify specific patterns in these character strings, as such:

```
library(devtools)
g_patterns_clean <- source_gist("164f798524fd6904236a")[[1]]
g_patterns_clean_strings <- source_gist("af70a76691aacf05c1bb")[[1]]

FA_EX_logic_vector <- grepl(g_patterns_clean_strings, pattern = "(FAEX|EXFA)+")
FA_EX_cluster <- subset(g_patterns_clean, FA_EX_logic_vector)
```

Let's now say that I want to allow for an arbitrary number of other characters in between FA and EX (or EX and FA), how can I specify that in the regex above?

Answer (score 0):

This is a flexible generalization of @eipi10's answer:

```
(FA.{0,2}EX|EX.{0,2}FA)
```

The `.` matches any character, and the `{0,2}` quantifier matches between 0 and 2 occurrences of `.`